# Visual Studio неправильная кодировка просмотра

Tags: visual-studio, кодировка

Когда я пишу на русском языке и сохраняю файл всё окей. Но потом я его закрываю и снова открываю, а там `краказябры`. Хотя когда я смотрю этот же файл например в `sublime text 3` всё окей. В поисках ошибки я заметил такую фигню: когда я сохраняю файл в кодировке `UTF-8(с сигнатурой)`, закрываю, открываю файл, проверяю какая кодировка стоит, а там `windows-1251`. И я не понимаю почему как где и когда. Помогите!

UPD: это появилось после какого-то странного бага в отладчике. А с теми файлами, что я создал ранее - всё окей.

Comment: У вас есть файл(ы) .editorconfig в папках проекта? Если есть, поищите там настройку charset. Если не создавали этот файл сами (Студия может его сгенерировать при любом вашем неловком движении), просто удалите его (или их - может быть несколько в разных папках)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov ну я скачивал расширение на автоустановку кодировки UTF-8 без BOM

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov ну короче. Я удалил эти расширения. Но теперь придется менять кодировку на UTF-8 без BOM самому

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov да нету его у меня. А пишу чтобы вы знали что всё норм